# passing variables as a value in map

Tags: dictionary, variables, terraform

```
  variable "selected_role" {
    type = map(list(string))
    default = {
      "devops"  = var.devops_arn
      "dbadmin" = var.dbadmin_arn
    }
  }
```

If devops_arn and dbadmin_arn variables are having list of managed policy ARNs. so, can i pass these variables as a value in map variable like above ?. I just blocked in this. quick help please

passing variables inside map as a value

Comment: 1. That default value does not conform to the specified `type` in the declaration. 2. Default values within declarations cannot be variable.

Comment: OK, Thanks for the quick response !!! but I have ARNs of these roles (devops and dbadmin) and need to call them in main.tf in the count variable. so, if this approach is not valid then how to proceed with other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't do that, however within your plan, you could have some conditional to transform your variable into a more "normalized" form.  Maybe try somethign like this:

```
variable "selected_role" {
    type = map(string)
    default = null
  }

locals {
  normalized_selected_role = var.selected_role == null ? {
    "devops"  = var.devops_arn
    "dbadmin" = var.dbadmin_arn
  } : var.selected_role
}
```

Comment: Be careful with comparing a `map(string)` to `{}`. The expression `{}` produces a value of type `object({})`, so that will always return false as currently written -- values of different types are never equal.

Comment: A slight tweak that would make this work: set the default to `null` instead, and then check `var.selected_role == null`. Null values are equal to one another regardless of type.

Comment: Updated the comparison in the answer.

Comment: one doubt> how to call selected_role into main.tf, i just need to pass ARNs via selected_role. two possible ways but i am bit confused which to use.                                    
    1. count  = var.createssorole ? length(var.selected_role[local.normalized_selected_role]) 2. count = var.createssorole ? length(local.normalized_selected_role[var.selected_role] i think the second will work but not sure Note=> if selected_role will be devops then it should fetch var.devops_arns which is having 2 managed policy ARNs

Comment: Neither, actually.  I have found out the hard way NEVER go by count unless you never (and WILL never) care about ordering and correlating to other lists, which since you are using a map, you probably DO care about correlations.  In that case, you should always use for_each.